# Find object in array which is not exist and it returns inconsistent value instead of undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

When I try to find a non-exist object element in an array, it's shown inconsistent result instead of undefined .., why?

```
const a = [{ id: 1, name: '1' }, { id: 2, name: '2' }, { id: 3, name: '3' }, { id: 4, name: '4' }]
const b = a.find(result => result.id = 100)
console.log(b)


// result { id: 100, name: '1' }
```

Comment: You used [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2) (`=`) instead of [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) or [identity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) (`==` or `===`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below snippet.

```js
const a = [{ id: 1, name: '1' }, { id: 2, name: '2' }, { id: 3, name: '3' }, { id: 4, name: '4' }];
const b = a.find(result => result.id === 100);
console.log(b);
```

Your mistake is that you are using `=` instead of `===` in Array.find